# Create facebook's image picker for android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I'm attempting to duplicate facebook's style for an image picker (user can select an image from camera or gallery) which includes a image sized button with a camera icon nested as the first "image" in the gallery. How would this be achieved? Would it involve creating my own grid for all photos + camera icon?

(designing for Marshmallow and up)

Comment: Hi Welcome to stack**overflow**. Please refer [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

I found one of this ImagePicker and look alike to Facebook's ImagePicker so maybe you might want to consider using it.
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6925